# write a query which will fetch the top 3 students names in each subject along with the marks they score

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL need a query for below scenario:

2 tables : 1st one with roll no, name
2nd with roll no,subject n marks
Need to write a query which will fetch the top 3 students names in each subject along with the marks they score

I have written below query for the above but it is not fetching correct results:

```
SELECT TABLE1.NAME, MAX(TABLE2.MARKS) 
FROM 
TABLE1 
INNER JOIN 
TABLE2
ON TABLE1.ROLL_NO = TABLE2.ROLL_NO
GROUP BY SUB
ORDER BY TABLE2.MARKS
HAVING ROWNUM <3
```

Below is the table data:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT ( ROLL_NO INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (1,'NIKHIL');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (2,'VARUN');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (3,'NISHANT');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (4,'VISHAL');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (5,'GOURAV');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (6,'HEMANT');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (7,'SHUBHAM');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (8,'DHAWAN');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (9,'GAUTAM');


CREATE TABLE MARKS ( ROLL_NO INT, SUBJECT VARCHAR(20), MARKS INT);
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('1','MATHS','92');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('1','SCIENCE','80');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('1','ENGLISH','98');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('1','HINDI','81');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('2','MATHS','89');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('2','SCIENCE','100');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('2','ENGLISH','81');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('2','HINDI','82');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('3','MATHS','98');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('3','SCIENCE','92');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('3','ENGLISH','88');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('3','HINDI','83');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('4','MATHS','88');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('4','SCIENCE','82');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('4','ENGLISH','85');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('4','HINDI','97');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('5','MATHS','94');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('5','SCIENCE','90');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('5','ENGLISH','97');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('5','HINDI','89');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('6','MATHS','89');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('6','SCIENCE','82');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('6','ENGLISH','84');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('6','HINDI','85');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('7','MATHS','82');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('7','SCIENCE','100');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('7','ENGLISH','92');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('7','HINDI','98');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('8','MATHS','99');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('8','SCIENCE','91');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('8','ENGLISH','86');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('8','HINDI','82');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('9','MATHS','100');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('9','SCIENCE','95');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('9','ENGLISH','81');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('9','HINDI','81');
```

Comment: Share the tables with example data.. You will get better hulp that way.. the solution involves MySQL's user variables because ROWNUM doesnt exists in MySQL

Comment: If you're new to PL/SQL, why tag MySQL?

Comment: I believe you're using Oracle

Comment: I have updated the table data above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER window function like this.

```
SELECT
 *
FROM ( 

  SELECT
     MARKS.ROLL_NO
   , MARKS.SUBJECT
   , MARKS.MARKS 
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ROLL_NO ORDER BY MARKS DESC) AS rank 
  FROM
   MARKS
) MARKS_RANKED
INNER JOIN
 STUDENT
ON
 MARKS_RANKED.ROLL_NO = STUDENT.ROLL_NO
 WHERE 
  rank <= 3
```

demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05776/41